# Git:pull the specified version

Tags: git, pull

there!

I have use git some days and I don't use the command line,I use the msysgit and tortoiseGit GUI.when I use this,I encounter two questions.

First:assume that I have commit some times(eg,5),when I remove the local repo,how can I pull the specified version(eg,3)?

Second:when I keep sync with the remote repo,but I remove one single file(eg,config.php),how can I pull the specified file that I remove?

sorry for my bad english!but please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is good enough to follow, but your questions are relatively ill-posed (hence someone's vote to close it). As many Git experts note, to use Git effectively, you *must* understand how it works, not just "what command should I run?". I'd suggest reading one or all of these guides:

- http://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/git/
- http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/
- http://gitolite.com/gcs/

And then see if you actually need to ask your question at all.

Comment: Thanks in advance!maybe you are right!but I  have already read some docs and I use the GUI not command line about git!In my work,I do not often use git,so I select tortoise as my tool.also,I just don't want to spend muchu time on git!I am foolished,sorry for this!